# ignorespace and unskip in verbatim/listings?

Tags: macros, tex-core, listings, verbatim, catcodes

I am writing a `\bashDemo` macro that will (a) execute its argument in a shell, e.g., bash, script, and (b) display the argument in a listings. So,

```
\bashDemo
ls -ls > myfiles
\END
```

will both run `ls -ls >myfiles` using the bash command shell, and will display using `lstlistings` this command within the document. The problem I have is that in consuming characters in a verbatim fashion, I have a newline both at the beginning and at the end of the argument. How do I get rid of these?

Here is my code (it is based on `tobiShell.sty`):

```
\lstdefinestyle{bash}{basicstyle={\ttfamily}}
\newwrite\ScriptFile
\edef\ScriptFileName{\jobname.sh}

% Store the argument into our script file.
\newcommand\generateScriptFile[1]{%      
    \immediate\openout\ScriptFile\ScriptFileName
    \immediate\write\ScriptFile{#1}%
    \immediate\closeout\ScriptFile
}

% Store the list of tokens in the argument into our script file
% and then list the contents of that file, prefixed by a "%".
\newcommand\listScriptFile[1]{%
   % The following does not work as expected.
  \generateScriptFile{\%\ignorespaces #1\unskip}\relax
  \lstinputlisting[style=bash]{\bashescScriptFileName}\relax
  \relax
}

\newcommand\bashDemo{\bashDemoI}

{% Define \bashDemoI
  \catcode`\^^M=13%
  \gdef\bashDemoI{%
    \bgroup
    \def\do##1{\catcode`##1 12\relax}%
    \catcode`\^^M=13%
    \def^^M{^^J}%
    \dospecials%
    \bashDemoII%         
  }%
}

{% Define \bashDemoII
  \catcode`\@=0\relax%
  @catcode`@\=12@relax%
  @gdef@bashDemoII#1\END{@relax% 
    @generateScriptFile{#1}@relax%
    @immediate@write18{bash@space@ScriptFileName@space}@relax%
    @listScriptFile{#1}@relax%
    @egroup@relax%
  }@relax%
}
```

Comment: You could have a look on the source code of `ydoc` which does something similar. I remove the trailing and leading new lines as well there.

Comment: Just some other tips: You can replace `\def\do##1{\catcode\`##1 12\relax}` with `\let\do\@makeother` and `\catcode\`\^^M=13` with `\catcode\`\^^M\active`. I think you want `\@percentchar` instead of `\%`. The verbatim `\END` could be more easily inserted using the common `\lcchar`/`\lowercase` trick. I like `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` much more then the `{`, `}` for this kind of definitions, because they are much more readable.

Comment: @Martin: many many thanks for the wonderful tips!!!

Comment: @Yossi Gil: You are welcome. Removing trailing and leading new lines is a little stupid. I currently have the issue with empty content. In `ydoc` I have an own definition of the `macrocode` environment. If it is empty the leading and trailing new-lines are the same! :-)

Comment: @Martin: Thanks again. I took a look at your code, coming up with a solution, which is not as general purpose as yours, seems to satisfy the needs of this particular domain. See below.

Comment: @Martin: I did not quite get what you meant in saying that "The verbatim \END could be more easily inserted using the common \lcchar/\lowercase trick."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to gentle Martin Scharrer for leading me to a satisfactory answer. The solution described below is not as general as his code in the `ydoc` package, but is good enough (I think) for my purposes.

The trick is to define the `bashDemoII` macro in such a way that it would gobble the end of line characters before and after the contents, i.e.,

```
 @gdef@bashDemoII^^M#1^^M\END
```

However, this would not work unless you do

```
  \catcode`\^^M\active
```

before hand. So, the complete definition of `\bashDemoII` is as follows:

```
\begingroup    % Define \bashDemoII
  \catcode`\@=0\relax%
  @catcode`@\=12@relax%
  @gdef@bashDemoII#1\END{@relax% 
    @generateScriptFile{#1}@relax%
    @immediate@write18{bash@space@ScriptFileName@space}@relax%
    @listScriptFile{#1}@relax%
    @egroup@relax%
  }@relax%
\endgroup
```

Comment: You can also use the `bashful` package as illustrated at this question on [how to automatically include command line session output in documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31542/how-to-automatically-include-command-line-session-output-in-documents/31866#31866)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a suggestion: you are working on so-called *literate programming*: code and documentation are contained in a file from which code and documentation can be extracted and processed. (Donald Knuth developed TeX as a literate program and coined the term.)

You might want to take a look at a literate programming system like *NoWeb*. Maybe you have heard of *Sweave*, which is a literate programming system for the *R* language. All these systems use LaTeX as part of a tool chain but use other tools as well. Literate programming probably works best on Unix systems.