# nice tilde in listings with indent working

Tags: formatting, listings, tilde

I am trying to have a nice tilde when using the `listings` package

Inspired by an answer here:
[The correct way to type tilde?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187761/the-correct-way-to-type-tilde?rq=1)

I tried the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\lstdefineformat{R}{~=\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textasciitilde}
\lstset{language=R,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        format=R,
        columns=fixed,
        basewidth=0.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
y ~ x + z +
    w
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

which gives me the tilde I want (and prefer over the `literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1` solution where the tilde looks out of place to me).

But now the indenting does not work.  Weirdly if I use `showspaces=true` it will work but I really don't want to see the underscores.

Why does the indenting no longer work?  Is there any way I can use this tilde using the `literate` argument?

For reference here is the standard tilde solution for which indenting works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\lstset{language=R,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        columns=fixed,
        basewidth=0.5em,
        literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
y ~ x + z +
    w
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The tilde is too thin and large relative to the rest of the characters.  The natural thing to try was to combine the solutions and attempt `literate={~}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textasciitilde}}1` but this didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `literate` option works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\lstset{language=R,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        columns=fixed,
        basewidth=0.5em,
        literate={~}{{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont \textasciitilde}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
y ~ x + z +
    w
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image]