# Displaying Linux commands in LaTeX

Tags: linux, emphasis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syntax Coloring in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex)
>   [Unix Command Highlighting latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/unix-command-highlighting-latex)

I am  after some advice on how to display Linux terminal commands into LaTeX, so that they are indented and look different from normal text.

I have tried to insert the following into LaTeX

```
  $\emph {wget http://etc...................}
```

this outputs the wget onto a single line and then the part starting http onto another line. I want it all to appear on one line. Can someone body please give me some advice.

Comment: Could you give us more of your code?   I'm getting the output as you seem to want it.  Also, for command line text I'd used `\ttfamily`.  Finally, you've got a stand alone `$` which should either be `\$` or not there at all.

Comment: See the answer of of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46953/unix-command-highlighting-latex

Comment: At a simple level remember LaTeX's standard command `\verb` and the environement `verbatim`.  For more sophisticated formatting see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/867/15925

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the features provided by the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\noindent See the following command :
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
  $ wget http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Listing]

Comment: What if my command is long and cuts off at the margin?

Answer (score 25):

You can also use the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\noindent See the following command :
\begin{minted}{bash}
  $ wget http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled result of above code]

You need Pygments and the `--shell-escape` flag when you compile.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).  It uses the Python library Pygments to provide some syntax highlighting.

If you don't need syntax highlighting, [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) is nice for typesetting verbatim text with custom indentation, frames, line numbers, etc.  Internally, `pythontex` uses much of `fancyvrb`, combined with syntax highlighting from Pygments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\setpygmentspygopt{bash}{style=default} %Set syntax highlighting style
\setpygmentsfv{xleftmargin=4ex} %Pass fancyvrb options, in this case, left margin

\begin{document}

\noindent Block use:
\begin{pygments}{bash}
$ wget http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{pygments}
And after the block.

Inline use:  \pygment{bash}{wget http://tex.stackexchange.com}.  And after inline

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `listings` packages:

Add the following to the header:

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

And type your code like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
print('print me')
\end{lstlisting}
```

For more detail, read the Wikibooks chapter about the package. [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings)

Comment: I like your answer :) I think you would have received more up votes if you had made a complete MWE, as the other answer did; [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)