# Define minted environment as a verbatim environment in texmaker

Tags: texmaker, minted

I use the minted environment in order to insert source code in a document. Contrary to `lstlistings` or `verbatim` environment, Texmaker does interpret the contains of `minted` environment.

For example if I have a `$` inside a `bash` script all lines below will be green because Texmaker considers that an equation began inside the minted environment.

Does it exist a way to configure Texmaker to do with minted as it does with `listings` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it turns out to be a feature request for texmaker.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is 'no', at least not at present. Looking through the interface, while you can adjust the colours used for different environments, you can't alter how these are defined. There is also 'syntax.txt' or similar file to allow adjustment outside of the GUI, either. Thus the only way to address this issue seems to be to make a feature request to the Texmaker maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a straightforward solution but a workaround in TeXmaker is to add `%$` to balance the `$` in bash script to regain the normal syntax colouring in `minted` environment: [Related issue](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=662&can=1&q=green&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary) at TeXmaker issue tracker

Demo example borrowed from TeX.SX: [Displaying Linux commands in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84204/15717)  by User [You](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/66/you)

[image]