# Interactive PDF, Latex and Article of the Future

Tags: acrotex

Influenced by [Elsevier's Article of the future](http://www.articleofthefuture.com/S0022314X08001856/) and this [blog post](http://contributioneconomy.net/2012/11/21/how-an-academic-article-of-the-future-should-look/) where someone writes an article with Apple's iAuthor and gets many functionalities (clicking on references show a balloon with the given reference, or previous definitions and theorems, etc...).

I am conscient of the existence of acrotex and the many hyper-referencing capabilities it offers, quizzes, etc, but can something like these "floating balloons" can be implemented in pdf with latex? It would be interesting as having a free substitute for Apple software is always a good idea.

Comment: `pgfplots` uses javascript to allow dynamic interaction with plots. While I wrote that stuff, I stumbled over the problem that you cannot modify the document object model unless the complete document is signed. That, in turn is impossible with pdftex as it seems (?). Recently, I found that it might be possible with `dvipdfmx` - perhaps that would be an option.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-document-level-javascript-in-latex-documents?rq=1

Comment: I don’t know, whether I’ve misunderstood you, but see package `pdfcomment` for its features and answer(s) to the question [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig).

Comment: To the OP: I put the bounty because I find this issue interesting, but I would prefer to award it to the answer accepted by you. Maybe you could comment on the existing answers whether or not they meet your interest, or what should be enhanced.

Comment: Huh, so article of the future domain was allowed to lapse (if I search for the Elseiver site even their link is broken).  Someone should buy it and do something amusing with it.

Answer (score 19):

***Note:*** incoming version 0.5 of [ocgx package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) uses [ocg-p package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) (instead of `ocg.sty` from documentation of Asymptote).

Here is a very simple example using [ocgx package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) and TikZ. You can click on equation to show its name if your PDF viewer is compatible with OCGs (like Adobe Reader, Foxit Reader, Evince...).

*(Note: this example requires two compilations.)*

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]%
{\tikz[overlay,baseline,remember picture]\coordinate(#1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \switchocg{mee}{$E = mc^2$}\tikzmark{mee}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \begin{scope}[ocg={ref=mee,status=invisible,name=Mass Energy Equivalence}]
      \node[rectangle callout,callout absolute pointer=(mee),fill=orange]
      at ([shift={(+3,+1)}]mee) {Mass Energy Equivalence};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my answer to [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig): “The package `fancytooltips` requires the package `ocg` …”.

Comment: @HarishKumar The [ocg.sty](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/asymptote/doc/ocg.sty) files comes from `asymptote` documentation...

Comment: @Speravir: * jumping to the link:

Comment: @PaulGaborit: very nice solution and, BTW, thanks for the `ocgx` package (I used it for my thesis presentation in a plot to explain better some curves with a great success). I've adapted your solution into [Explanatory bubbles in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83783/explanatory-bubbles-in-beamer/83786#83786) to have basically two commands for doing the job. Oh.. forgot: +1 of course `:)`

Comment: Cool package, indeed. I especially like the non-JavaScript take that would free us from Acrobat/Reader. Are you aware of any non-Adobe PDF reader for OSX that can deal with OCGs?

Comment: Oh, I just figured that evince is available for OS X via MacPorts. Just trying to install it...

Comment: While evince does work on OS X (needs an X11 server), the OCG stuff unfortunately doesn't :-(

Comment: @Daniel MacPorts version of Evince is 2.30. Fink version of Evince is 2.22. On Linux, the current version of Evince is 3.6! So, on Mac OS X, you must use Adobe Reader.

Comment: It's just that I hate Adobe Reader and are hoping for alternatives... It's a resource hog and crappy PDF viewer on OS X. Eventually, Apple should incorporate OCGs in their PDFKit, on which basically all other PDF viewers for apple are built.

Comment: @Daniel You can try FoxitReader (a Windows application) via wine...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: The new package `ocg-p` is installed in MiKTeX. If you plan to update `ocgx`, you should either change to it or at least make a remark in the manual. See also my update in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83039/9237 – “Since MiKteX update from Dec 5 2012 you can _(and perhaps should)_ use the new package `ocg-p` […]”

Comment: @Speravir Migration is in progress... But, see my [recent question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86027).

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you are looking for a purely `LaTeX` approach. If that is what you want, then it seems Paul Gaborit's `ocgx` package is the way to go. But you tagged your question as `acrotex` which uses javascript to enable its mouseover features. The manuals of `acrotex` also have mouseover features. In [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig) I used `fancytooltips` which also uses `acrotex`.

Looking at the `pdf`'s you linked to, it seems that some javascript magic was also implemented. My answer and Speravir's additional answer to [Mouseover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig) will greatly help in this case. There are also a lot of examples provided in the devloper's site: http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/.

Here is a sample article. (I'm sorry for the inconsistency of topics in content and bibliography`:)`. I used different sources for it--the math is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle while the bibliography is from `biblatex`'s `biblatex-examples.bib`. *(I am lazy and almost proud of it)*.

Read through [Mouseover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig) for the explanation about compiling the code in different platforms.

```
% myfile1.tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
This is an example of a citation \parencite{markey,westfahl:space,aksin}. 

Here is a theorem.

\begin{theorem}[Argument Principle]
If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\oint \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2\pi i(N-P)
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

$N$ and $P$ of Equation \eqref{eq:1} denote respectively the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside the contour $C$, with each zero and pole counted as many times as its multiplicity, respectively order, indicates.

\printbibliography.
\end{document}
```

I compiled this in terminal using

```
perl fancy-preview myfile1 --fancy_options="previewall,nosoap"
```

The `previewall` option enables mouseover pop-ups even if the link being referenced to is on the same page. I used it here just for the sake of the example but I personally think that enabling mouseover for equations when one can already see the equations on the same page is nonsensical. `nosoap`, the default, removes the soap-shaped figures (tooltipmarks) on the top of the links.

Here is the output.

[image]
[image]
[image]

To enable `tooltipmarks`, compile with

```
perl fancy-preview myfile1 --fancy_options="previewall"
```

To use any of the four pre-defined `tooltipmarks` of `fancytooltips`, you may use `--fancy_options="previewall,tooltipmark=1` where you can replace `1` with `2,3`, or `4`.

### Disadvantages

1. You can only use `Acrobat` or `Adobe Reader` since other pdf readers like `evince` have no javascript capabilities.
2. The files are bloated.
3. The `tooltipmarks`, according to the `fancytooltips` manual can *disturb the text* and I agree.
4. The mouseover effects are sometimes annoying especially when you unintentionally mouse over the `tooltipmark`.
5. As reminded by Paul Gaborit in comment, the developer of `AcroTex` withdrew the bundle from `TeXLive` and the newer versions are now commercial. Although an older version available from CTAN is included in `MikTeX`.

Comment: Another disadvantage: `AcroTeX` bundle is not provided by TeXLive by explicit request of its authors (now, AcroTeX bundle is a commercial product even if an earlier version exists in CTAN with LPPL licence).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the reminder. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: AcroTeX Presentation bundle is commercial, but the price is low and moreover, about the same functionality (libraries for inserting javascripts etc.) is in the free AcroTeX eDucation bundle. IMHO, this free AcroTeX eDucation bundle is better, since it allows to use pdftex and no postprocessing with Adobe Acrobat is necessary.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I wonder if this can somehow be used with opentype fonts and full unicode. I asked this as a new question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111859/interactive-pdf-latex-and-article-of-the-future-with-opentype-truetype-fonts

Answer (score 10):

It is possible with LaTeX to program anything you want in a `pdf`. You might even make your document talk (see [Hello World in pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/hello-world-in-pdflatex)). Effectively though you are writing JavaScript to a file via LaTeX.

However, my personal opinion is that once you start talking about presenting information in many different formats and media, you need to turn your thinking around. For example, I find it easier to *start* writing a document in a browser window (see [LaTeX mark-up as a generic mark-up language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83588/latex-mark-up-as-a-generic-mark-up-language)) and sending the same mark-up to a LaTeX engine to produce the pdf. It costed me a few evenings work, but is substantially easier than trying to coerce LaTeX to produce the html patterns I want.

What I am suggesting is:

```
   info - > transformer       - > type of presentation
        - > htmtransformer    - > html
        - > voice transformer - > accesible document
        - > LaTeX             - > beautiful document
```

Remember that you want your document to be able to survive as long as possible, so it is better to keep the basic LaTeX or other mark-up to a minimum.

Comment: There is a professional discipline very similar to your approach called [cross media publishing](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Media_Publishing). A general property of this approach is that however you originally planned to use it, finally you end up having a content semantics in you information source which is the *lowest common denominator* of all the formats you are able to convert to. Hence, this is very different from pure print publishing which LaTeX is aimed at.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks for the link. In my early days of computing we had a similar problem with all the different file formats for data or otherwise (and no theory:). Agreed that one has to look at the lowest common denominator of all the formats. So far idea is working without the theory:)