# How to emulate \pdfstartlink and \pdfendlink with xetex?

Tags: xetex, pdf, primitives

In my `ocgx` package, I would use the new `ocg-p` package instead of the `ocg` package. With pdflatex or lualatex, all is good. But with xelatex, I obviously can't use `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink` (these primitives are provided by `pdftex` or `luatex`).

How to emulate these two primitives with xetex?

Here is an example of current code in my `ocgx` package:

```
\long\def\switchocg#1#2{%
  \def\ocgx@list{}%
  \ocgx@listOCG#1 ENDOFOCGS %
  \leavevmode%
  \pdfstartlink user {%
    /Subtype /Link
    /A << /S/SetOCGState /State [/Toggle \ocgx@list] >>
    /Border [0 0 0]
  }%
  #2\pdfendlink%
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `texdoc dvipdfmx` the pair of specials

```
\special{pdf:bann <<dict>>}
\special{pdf:eann}
```

allow for producing breakable annotations with dvipdfmx/XeTeX in analogy to the pdfTeX commands `\pdfstartlink`/`pdfendlink`.

Thus,

```
\long\def\switchocg#1#2{%
  \def\ocgx@list{}%
  \ocgx@listOCG#1 ENDOFOCGS %
  \leavevmode%
  \special{pdf:bann <<
    /Subtype /Link
    /A << /S/SetOCGState /State [/Toggle \ocgx@list] >>
    /Border [0 0 0]
  >>}%
  #2%
  \special{pdf:eann}%
}
```

Comment: Unlike pdfTeX/LuateX, XeTeX/(x)dvipdfm(x) does not support nested annotations.

Comment: @Heiko: Do you think of something like `\pdfstartlink user {...} ... \pdfstartlink user {...} ... \pdfendlink ... \pdfendlink`? Doesn't seem to be relevant for @Paul's problem. What might this be good for? Do mouse events bubble through superimposed PDF annotations?

Comment: The question was about emulating `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink` with XeTeX. `\pdfstartlink` can be nested, `\special{pdf:bann}` cannot.

Comment: @Heiko: I am pretty sure that nesting links, that is, the possibility for `\switchocg{foo}{footext\switchocg{bar}{bartext}footext cont'd}`, isn't really wanted by the OP. Maybe @Paul could comment on this.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for your excellent answer (I looked at the xetex documentation and not at the dvipdfmx documentation).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for your comment about nested annotations.