# How to use pdf:bann and pdf:eann into a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, ocg, ocg-p

*(This question follows up [How to emulate \pdfstartlink and \pdfendlink with xetex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86027/14500))*

**Note**:  I used the last [CVS version of TikZ/PGF](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html).

With `xelatex`, I would like to create annotations in tikz nodes. The following MWE shows my problem: the location of the *second switch* (via TikZ) is bad.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocg-p}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mypdfstartlink#1{%
  \special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link /Border [1 1 1] /A << #1 >> >>}%
}
\def\mypdfendlink{%
  \special{pdf:eann}%
}
\long\def\switchocg#1#2{%
  \leavevmode%
  \mypdfstartlink{ /S/SetOCGState /State %
    [/Toggle \csname OCGpdfobj#1\endcsname\space] }%
  #2%
  \mypdfendlink%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ocg}{ocg 1}{ocg1}{1}
  Some text...
\end{ocg}

\switchocg{ocg1}{text switch}

\tikz\node{\switchocg{ocg1}{tikz switch}};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Result of \listfiles:

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   ocg-p.sty    2012/12/01 v0.3 Optional Content Group in a PDF document
 eso-pic.sty    2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/11/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.25)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pgfsys.sty    2012/03/30 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.38)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2012/08/27 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.22)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem with XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9):

> [image: Result]

Adding `\listfiles` prints this version list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   ocg-p.sty    2012/12/01 v0.3 Optional Content Group in a PDF document
 eso-pic.sty    2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the last [CVS version of TikZ/PGF](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html).