# pgfplots with SQL data

Tags: pgfplots, sql

I was wondering whether it is possible to retrieve data directly from SQL to generate *.dat file and draw plots with pgfplots, like for example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   title=Inv. cum. normal,
   xlabel={$x$},
   ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] table {*.dat} -> data retrieve directly from SQL database;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the data file is a text file with properly formatted content (i.e. as a table with comma/space/etc separated data), it doesn't matter what you used to create that file. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Also, note https://github.com/bingmann/sqlplot-tools

Comment: But, do you think it would be possible to write te query inside the .tex document, for example: select from something ... and this result would be the *.dat file?

Comment: You could try the `bashful` package: Example at [How to automatically include command line session output in documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31542/how-to-automatically-include-command-line-session-output-in-documents/).

Comment: pgfplots has an input mode `\addplot shell [<options>]{ shell commands };` which allows to execute arbitrary shell commands. If you ha ve a sql command which spits out properly formatted CSV data, pgfplots will be able to read it. I believe the interface builds on top of the gnuplot interface, so you may need to check if it works.

Comment: Following the comments, I have tried this: \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{bashful} 

\begin{document} 

\bash[stdout]
mysql -u username -ppassword  -D database  -e "SELECT Date,Settle FROM table" >"/directory/file.dat"
\END

\end{document}, but I received line 1:mysql: command not found, even though when I run this directly from terminal it correctly generates the file. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to succeed doing the following, which is a great integration tool!:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{bashful} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot,statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}



\begin{filecontents}{soyprice.dat}
Date    Settle
2016-08-02  985.25
2016-08-03  990.5
2016-08-04  990.5
2016-08-05  1003.75
2016-08-08  1018.75
2016-08-09  1022
2016-08-10  1017
2016-08-11  1022.25
2016-08-12  1003.25
2016-08-15  1023.75
2016-08-16  1019.5
2016-08-17  1030.5
2016-08-18  1032.25
2016-08-19  1027
2016-08-22  1035.25
2016-08-23  1034.25
2016-08-24  1030.75
2016-08-25  998.25
2016-08-26  990.75
2016-08-29  983.25
2016-08-30  965.5
2016-08-31  960
2016-09-01  959
2016-09-02  968.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bash[stdout]

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql (YOUR PATH TO MYSQL) -u YOURUSERNAME -pYOURPASSWORD -e "SELECT * FROM YOURDATABASE" > soyprice.dat
\END

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
           xlabel=Date, ylabel=Settle,table/col sep=space|tab|,
           date coordinates in=x,
           date ZERO=2016-08-01,
               xticklabel style={rotate=90},
               enlarge x limits = false,
               xticklabel={\month-\day},
               ymin=900,
               ymax=1100,
               minor y tick num=25,
              xmin=2016-08-02,
              xmax=2016-09-02
          title={Preço da soja - CME},
]
\addplot[blue] table [x={Date},y={Settle}] {soyprice.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```